# Visual Studio 2015 Thinks Windows 10 is Pre-Windows XP

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Today I installed Visual Studio 2015 on my laptop, though I just realised I didn't make the custom install option and I cannot write code in c++ . I tried installing the c++ redistriputable , but there was an error that said I should be using windows XP or newer (although I use windows 10?!?) . I can see the c++ redistriputable pack on my computer programs though. Please help, I need visual studio for a college project! Thank you!

Comment: Re-run the installer?

Comment: there's a repair option. Choose it.

Comment: Rerun installer. The Redistributable package is necessary when you want to ship your built program to others who do not have VStudio installed.

Answer (score 1):

You will either need to re-run setup and select the required options or alternatively, navigate to the New Project window in the IDE and look for the 'Install Microsoft Foundation Classes for C++" template. Running it should install the required libraries.

Please reference the following MS guide - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/07/24/setup-changes-in-visual-studio-2015-affecting-c-developers/